# Mongoose update results with exactly which fields got modified

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

- I have multiple update REST APIs written in node.js which use mongodb
  as the backend DB.
- These update APIs are atomic in nature and at a
  time update individual sections of the mongodb document for a user profile
   **example**: location API, personal Info API etc.

I am looking for a capability to know which individual fields are modified within the document. for instance, If the location API contains country, state, city and if the update was really made to country. I want to track country as the only field change.

Mongoose does not report the fields which are really for modified in the document.

Below is the sample:

```
Model.users.update({_id: "12345"}, {$set: update}, {upsert:true}, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err);
 ----
});
```

Response:

```
{ ok: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  n: 1,
  lastOp: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1469188533 },
  electionId: 5765d40f7dd9376cd6345122
```

}

Comment: Use the [**`findOneAndUpdate()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) API

Comment: does not work. do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

use mongoose Middleware for this purpose

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```js
schema.post('update', function(doc, next) {

        // this._update.$set  contains all the fields which are updated 
        if (this._update.$set.country) {
          concole.log('country is modified');
        }




    });
```

Comment: how do i pass my condition here?

Comment: ok now I understand that this is kind like a trigger on the the object. This code will listen to the changes. But I am trying to know if the value really updated or not.

Comment: if (this._update.$set.country) checks the value if it is modified or not

Comment: @AzeemMalik This is not accurate. Any fields passed to the $set operation of update will be listed there, whether they are different or same as the old value.